# C# change the color of the character on MS word document(.docx)

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, colors, ms-word

I am going to change the font color of the specific character instead of the whole paragraph on the MS document.
I'd like to do this in C#.

Now I can change the font color of the whole paragraph using DOCX library, but not able to change the character.

Looking to hearing any help.

Comment: Could you edit your post and add an example of your code?

Comment: Also, explain how to identify the character that should have different formatting applied.

Answer (score 0):

In the examples of this Library you have this code:

```
    // Insert a Paragraph into this document.
    var p = document.InsertParagraph();

    // Append some text and add formatting.
    p.Append( "This is an " ).Font( new Font( "Arial" )).Color(Color.Black)
    .Append( " E" ).Font( new Font( "Arial" )).Color( Color.Blue )
    .Append( " xample." ).Font( new Font( "Arial" )).Color( Color.Black);
```

In a paragraph you are able to add and format any kind of text. If you want to change the format of a letter, you need to add a letter + the format. This code will be displaying "This is an Example" and the letter "E" will be blue.